# How do I configure an ssl certificate with Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, config, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to install an SSL certificate on an Ubuntu server with Nginx (my project is on a Flask server). When I try to reach my domain with my current configuration, the site can't be reached and ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT appears. I'm also trying to redirect all http requests to https. This is my current .conf file:

```
server {

    server_name backlogtracker.live www.backlogtracker.live;
    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/backlogtracker.live/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/backlogtracker.live/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot     
}

server {
    if ($host = www.backlogtracker.live) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = backlogtracker.live) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name backlogtracker.live www.backlogtracker.live;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Even with https, I can't reach the domain. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

### Redirect http->https

This is a simple pattern for redirecting everything to https:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

It does not fit to all use-cases, but for most it is the simplest way without strange directives.

### Order

Order does in some cases make a difference in config-files. Nginx is working top-down, so to prevent strange behaviour I'd suggest to always write your config as a story. E.g. `return` immediately stops execution, so stuff behind that is not processed. I would suggest the order:

1. connection settings (listen, server_name)
2. general config (ssl, headers, log, etc)
3. logic (if, map, ..)
4. locations

### Headers for reverse proxy

I would suggest to always add headers (can be put in server-block to work for all locations):

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

### SSL Protocol

Disable old TLS protocols

```
ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
```

### Further inspection

If not working then:

- What is included in `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf`
- What are the logs of Flask and Nginx telling?
- Are both running on host machine (no containers)?